# Putting a legend in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a faceted `ggplot` graphic and would like to put a legend in each facet. For example, if I have the following plot, how could I make a legend in each facet corresponding to the lines that are contained within each facet (instead of one legend as it exists)?

```
data(mpg)

ggplot(mpg, aes(year, cty, group=manufacturer)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=manufacturer)) + facet_grid(.~drv)
```

[image]

The only solution I can come up with is to make three seperate plots using subsets. Is there a solution using `facet_grid()`?

Comment: I would use `gridExtra`'s `grid.arrange`.

Comment: not exactly what you're after, but looking at this graph I would suggest the directlabels package to annotate the lines directly in the panels.